# Detect when sound has stopped playing

Tags: bash, lua

So I have this script here:

sound.lua

```
os.execute('"./sound_play.sh" /home/$USER/FOLDER/FOLDER/canon.wav')
```

sound_play.sh

```
play -q $1 &
```

I need to be able to detect when it has stopped playing, *but*, it **can't** freeze the console while it plays.
It then needs to tell the LUA script that the sound is done playing.

Comment: You could get a list of active processes once a second in the `lua` script until the `play` process is no longer in it...

Comment: How exactly might I do that? Google isn't really helping...

Comment: Or your script could create a file called "finished" after playing the sound and your lua script could check every now and then to see if file "finished" exists.